# Conditional import or alternative in JavaScript (ReactJS WebApp)?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, internationalization, ecmascript-6

I'm implementing internationalization for a ReactJS webapp. 
How can I avoid loading all language files?

```
import ru from './ru';
import en from './en';

// next lines are not important for this question from here
import locale from 'locale';
const supported = new locale.Locales(["en", "ru"])

let language = 'ru';

const acceptableLanguages = {
    ru: ru,
    en: en,
}
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const browserLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    const locales = new locale.Locales(browserLanguage)
    language = locales.best(supported).code
}

// till here

// and here i'm returning a static object, containing all language variables
const chooseLang = () => {
    return acceptableLanguages[language];
}
const lang = chooseLang();

export default lang;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to dynamically load modules in ES6.

There is an upcoming [HTML Loader Spec](https://github.com/whatwg/loader) which will allow for this functionality, so you could use [a polyfill](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/tree/1.0) in order to use that.

```
const chooseLang = () => System.import(`./${language}`);
export default chooseLang;
```

However, this would now be promise-based so it would need to be called like so:

```
import language from "./language";
language.chooseLang().then(l => {
    console.log(l);
});
```

But bear in mind, that spec could change radically (or be dropped altogether).

Another alternative would be to not store your localizations as Javascript modules, but as JSON instead, e.g.

**en.json**

```
{ "hello_string": "Hi!" }
```

**language.js**

```
const chooseLang = () => {
    return fetch(`./${language}.json`)
        .then(response => response.json());
};
```

Again, this would be promise based so would need to be accessed as such:

```
import language from "./language";
language.chooseLang().then(l => {
    console.log(l.hello_string);
});
```

That solution would be fully ES6-compliant and would not rely on possible future features.

Comment: it's acceptable for my case to compile multiple bundles (with webpack), but i don't know how to conditionally exclude one of those imports at least at the moment of compilation. Any new ideas?

Comment: @stkvtflw If you're using webpack, you can just use `require('./en')`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I am late here, but I would like to answer the approach I am using. I have an async component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default (loader, collection) => (
  class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.Component = null;
      this.state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        loader().then((Component) => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component;
          this.setState({ Component });

        });
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.Component) {
        return (
          <this.state.Component { ...this.props } { ...collection } />
        )
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
);
```

And we call it using:

```
const page1 = asyncComponent(() => import('./page1')
  .then(module => module.default), { name: 'page1' });
```

and then we use it with:

```
  <Route path='/page1' component= {page1}/>
```

This will ensure that loading is done dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable) package - if you can somehow encapsulate your language files into components, this might solve your problem.