# Parsing a file path variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. 
Here is what I am trying

```
const path = "../locale/" + Properties.language  +"/labels.json";
    console.log(path);
    const labels = require("path");
    console.log(labels);
```

This does not work, but the following works fine. If someone can explain whats going on here

```
const labels = require("../locale/en-us/labels.json");
console.log(labels);
```

Comment: Note the path variable in the first code comes up fine

Comment: why a -ve vote, Please explain. IF you read down, I tried it with variable and string both

Comment: Can we see `Properties.language`?

Comment: You can't conditionally import modules I think.  Same goes with requiring them.
Check this thread for examples on how to go around this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929000/conditional-import-or-alternative-in-javascript-reactjs-webapp

Comment: If you're transpiling to a browser, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
require("path")
```

You just required the built-in module named `path`.

If you want to use a variable, you should actually use the variable, not a string.

Comment: I tried that initially I used it as a variable, but no luck :(

Comment: Like this 
require(path)

Comment: @MiteshPant: Why not? What happened?