# What's the best way to conditionally import a component from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So, the problem is, I have a component A, that should render a component B according to some condition. I could import B at the top and everything will be fine, but If the condition isn't met, I don't want to end up with all B's component code not needing it. The way im doing is:

```
let B;
if (condition) { B = require('./B.js' }
```

Does this make sense? Thanks.

The problem is that I'm getting the "Element type is invalid: expected a string" error.

Edit1: I'm using create-react-app

Edit2: **Solution:**

```js
let comp;
if(condition) { comp = require('./SomeComponent').default; }
```

Comment: This might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929000/conditional-import-or-alternative-in-javascript-reactjs-webapp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Webpack, you can perform a dynamic import along with having that import bundled separately from the component code.

```
const B = condition && import(/* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */ './b.js')
```

Otherwise you can simply use dynamic imports:

```
const B = condition && import('./b.js')
```

Comment: didn't know i could use "import" instead of "require" . Gonna try that one

Comment: As CJBLOC mentioned in his answer, you will need babel involved to use dynamic imports.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the "Element type is invalid: expected a string" error. I test with the import on the top of the file as usual and it worked. require or import dont get the same type of object/func/string...will investigate.

Comment: You might need to use B.default after the import, depending on how it is exported in the file.

Comment: yep, default did the trick, I had the same issue with Vue in the past. Thanks man!

Comment: @SteveVaughan Your answer saved me after hours of debugging!

Answer (score 1):

you can try dynamic import? Although it would require using babel/es6+
https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node#usage

```
if(x) {
 import('./B.js').then(B => this.setState({ B })
}
```

Comment: I would use react-loadable for that. But the problem is not the synchronous part of it, it's conditional rendering, not dynamic rendering. Thanks though :)